# form.validate_on_submit() does not work although everything is fine while submitting the form

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

> this is the route for registration form

```
@app.route("/register", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    form = RegisterForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        print(f"value submitted")
        # flash(f'Account created for {form.name.data}!', 'success')
        
        return redirect(url_for('homeLogin'))
    print("not validated")
    return render_template('dashboard/register.html',form=form)
```

> this is froms.py file

```
from wtforms import validators
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField, BooleanField , SelectField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length, Email, EqualTo
from pycountry import pycountry
from flask_wtf import Form

# Register Form Class
class RegisterForm(Form):
    name = StringField('Username', [Length(min=1, max=50)])
    company = StringField('company', [Length(min=4, max=25)])
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', [ DataRequired(), EqualTo('confirm', message='Passwords do not match') ])
    confirm = PasswordField('Confirm Password')
    country = SelectField(u'Country', choices=[(country.alpha_2, country.name) for country in pycountry.countries] , validate_choice=True)
    submit = SubmitField('Sign Up')
```

> my main file imports:

```
from app import app as app
from flask import Flask,render_template,request,session,redirect,url_for , flash
import helperFunctions as hf
from model import *
import math
from datetime import datetime
from forms import RegisterForm
```

> running the python file gives me output as :

FlaskWTFDeprecationWarning: "flask_wtf.Form" has been renamed to "FlaskForm" and will be removed in 1.0.
form = RegisterForm()

not validated

Comment: I fill the form correctly, its submission is passing all the validations  and page gets refereshed to the same page.

Answer (score -1):

in your registration route, try using:
if form.validate():
...

instead of using form.validate_on_submit()